# The output is nothing as how its supposed to look and I tried fixing it several times but I need assistance

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

The output is nothing as how its supposed to look and I tried fixing it several times but I need assistance.

My code:

```py
def main():
    fruit = open("fruit.txt")
    wordDict = {}
    for line in fruit:
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if len(word) > 0:
                word = word.lower()
                if word in wordDict.keys():
                    wordDict[word] += 1
                    print(word, "appears in line(s)", wordDict)
                else:
                    wordDict[word] = 1
    for key in sorted(wordDict):
        print(" {0} : {1} ".format(key, wordDict[key]))


main()
```

OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:

```
apples appear in line(s) 1
orange appears in line(s) 1 6
grapes appears in line(s) 1 2 3 6
bananas appears in line(s) 1 6
watermelon appears in line(s) 1 4
peaches appears in line(s) 1 4 
strawberries appears in line(s) 1 4
avocado appears in line(s) 2
cantaloupes appears in line(s) 2 5 
apricots appears in line(s) 2 5
nectarines appears in line(s) 2
lemons appears in line(s) 3
limes appears in line(s) 3
```

```
CURRENT OUTPUT:
```

grapes appears in line(s)
watermelon appears in line(s)
peaches appears in line(s)
strawberries
appears in line(s)
cantalopes appears in line(s)
orange appears in line(s)
grapes appears in line(s)

: 1
apples : 1
appricots : 1
appricots
: 1
avocado : 1
bananas : 1
bananas
: 1
cantalopes : 2
grapes : 3
grapes
: 1
lemons : 1
limes
: 1
nectarines : 1
orange : 2
peaches : 2
strawberries
: 2
watermelon : 2

````
``` FRUIT.TXT FILE
apples orange grapes bananas watermelon peaches strawberries
avocado cantalopes appricots nectarines grapes
grapes lemons limes
watermelon peaches strawberries
cantalopes appricots
orange grapes bananas
````

Comment: Can you attach `fruit.txt` file and your current output?

Comment: @asdasd the fruit.txt file is 
apples orange grapes bananas watermelon peaches strawberries
avocado cantalopes appricots nectarines grapes
grapes lemons limes
watermelon peaches strawberries
cantalopes appricots
orange grapes bananas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to do something like this:

```py
def main():
    with open('one.txt', 'r')as fruit:
        wordDict = {}
        for index, line in enumerate(fruit):
            words = line.strip().split(" ")
            for word in words:
                if len(word) <= 0:
                    continue
                word = word.lower()
                if word not in wordDict:
                    wordDict[word] = []
                wordDict[word].append(index+1) # +1 to start line number from 1 instead of 0

    for key in sorted(wordDict):
        print(key, "appears in line(s)", wordDict[key])


main()
```

Output:

```
apples appears in line(s) [1]
appricots appears in line(s) [2, 5]
avocado appears in line(s) [2]
bananas appears in line(s) [1, 6]
cantalopes appears in line(s) [2, 5]
grapes appears in line(s) [1, 2, 3, 6]
lemons appears in line(s) [3]
limes appears in line(s) [3]
nectarines appears in line(s) [2]
orange appears in line(s) [1, 6]
peaches appears in line(s) [1, 4]
strawberries appears in line(s) [1, 4]
watermelon appears in line(s) [1, 4]
```

Comment: yes, but the output is different, in the fruit.txt file there is a total of 6 lines.
 for instance, apples appear in line(s) 1
orange appears in line(s) 1,6
grapes appears in line(s) 1,2,3,6

Comment: Accept the answer if it solved your problem so that net person can refer to it easly.